# Resize multi-line text field

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

So I just returned to GUI programming after a long time on Mac OS X. I heard about this great feature called Auto Layout. For my project I want a very simple layout: a textfield dominating the window, with a couple buttons at the bottom. When I resize the window, I want the textfield to resize with it.

I thought that was simple task: constraints on the 4 edges and Height and Width >= what I have in Interface Builder:

[image]

If I set it like this, I can't resize the window vertically, only horizontally. If I drop either the Height or Width constraint, it will shrink to a tiny size in a corner.

How should I set my constraints so that the textfield resize with the window?

Comment: Hallo have you found a solution ?

Answer (score -1):

To resize text field with the window size you need to **add constraints to all the four edges of the text field**! As per your screen shot you haven't added any constraints to the right and bottom edge, instead you have added dimensions (or say height and width)!

And to avoid making text field terribly small you can add min-width and height to it.

Comment: I did all that in the question but it's not resizing as expected.

Comment: You can check out this video tutorial for more details https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hw85dOsQT3s